# multiple mysql query with group by

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

currently I am re factoring my code, At present I have

```
$query="SELECT DISTINCT TRIPID FROM trips_info WHERE userid=$userid";
    $results = $dbh->query($query)->fetchAll();
        foreach ($results as $i => $row)
        {
            $iquery="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM trips_data WHERE userid=$userid AND tripid=$row[0]";
            $iiqu="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM trips_data WHERE userid=$userid AND not killcount=0 AND tripid=$row[0]";
            $irow=$dbh->query($iquery)->fetch();
            $iirow=$dbh->query($iiqu)->fetch();
            array_push($tripsdata, $row[0]);
            array_push($tripsdata, $irow[0]);
            array_push($tripsdata, $iirow[0]);
        }
```

I am well aware that there must be a way to get a pdo with all the info I need with out the multiple  database connections in a loop. This is what I have so far (which does not work)

```
SELECT (
   (SELECT COUNT(id) as no FROM trips_data WHERE userid=1),
   (SELECT COUNT(id) as no FROM trips_data WHERE userid=1 AND not killcount=0)
) group by trips_data.tripid
```

my question is how do you add a group by statement to this kind of query?

What I hope to get is

tripid   points  kills,
1        5322    109, 
2       83939    17

Comment: Do you need to keep the duplicates or remove them??.. GROUP normally removes them.. UNION or UNION ALL can help you here

Answer (score 2):

if you had whatever "killcount" as null instead of 0, it would be

```
SELECT tripid, count(1), count(killcount) 
FROM trips_info ti, trips_data td WHERE ti.userid=? AND td.tripid=ti.tripid
GROUP BY td.tripid
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm making assumptions regarding your database schema, however I think this could be made into one query

```
SELECT
  ti.tripid, 
  COUNT(td_a) as 'trip_count_1', 
  COUNT(tb_b) as 'trip_count_2' 
FROM
  trips_info AS ti
INNER JOIN
  trips_data AS td_a ON td_a.tripid = ti.id
INNER JOIN
  trips_data AS td_b ON td_b.tripid = ti.id AND td_b.killcount > 0
WHERE
 ti.userid = ?
```

Comment: if I run this I get "unknown column in field list td_a", I can quite see why I am geting that error

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all you help in the end I took a different route and got this, which works fine

```
SELECT  
        tripid,
        SUM(CASE WHEN killcount >0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS kills, 
        count(id) AS points 
        FROM trips_data  
        WHERE userid=$userid
        GROUP BY tripid";
```

Comment: You ought to join this query with trips_info to get rid of the loop. otherwise this "refactoring" would be useless

Comment: err, this query does remove the need for a loop? it returns all the data from one query?

Comment: This one is not. But other queries, from Alex and me, do that.